# How to use AccessibilityEvent in Android to get the text, resourceid of all textviews on a particular screen of another App?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have created a class that extends AccessibilityService. The 'onAccessibilityEvent' method gives an accessibility event. How can it be used to iterate through all TextViews on the screen and get only textual data ? Also, how to read a webview's html data ?

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android developer site ([new link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#multilingual-tts), [old link on wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409072423/http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/accessibility/service.html)) has a good example. You can try:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
if (source == null) {
    return;
}

// Grab the parent of the view that fired the event.
AccessibilityNodeInfo rowNode = getListItemNodeInfo(source);
if (rowNode == null) {
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < rowNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo node = rowNode.getChild(i);
    if ("TextView".eaquals(node.getClassName())) {
         Log.i("text", node.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for heping out. I have another issue. I'm trying to access the content of a webview also. How can that be achieved ?

Comment: You mean get the html?

Comment: Why not use **onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent()**?

Comment: getListItemNodeInfo(source) not working